# How to avoid code blocking in a loop

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, stream, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to pull frames from a remote video streaming server, images are of type `mjpeg`, then upload to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage.

Through my testing, I am able to pull consistently ~30 images per second and save the frames in my machine. However, when I am trying to upload all individual frames to GCS with their client library, it will wait for the uploading process to finish first, then come back and upload a newly received frame.

For instance, in 1s, I'm expecting to receive and upload all `0...30` images, but because my code is asynchronous, it only uploads the latest image received in the loop.

Here's my code

```
class GCStream:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = storage.Client()
        self.bucket = self.client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        self.frame = None
        self.fileName = ""
        self.secondCount = 0
        self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second
        self.vs = VideoStream(src=REMOTE_STREAM_MJPEG).start()


    def uploadFrame(self):
        try:
            blob = self.bucket.blob("{}/{}/{}".format(RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY, self.fileName))
            blob.upload_from_filename(os.path.abspath(self.fileName))
            print("{} uploaded to {}/{}".format(self.fileName, RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY))
            os.remove(self.fileName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


    def readFrame(self):
        while True:
            self.frame = self.vs.read()
            self.secondCount = self.secondCount + 1

            if datetime.datetime.now().second != self.startSecond:
                self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second
                self.secondCount = 0

            if self.frame is not None:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, 800)
                self.fileName = "{}-{}.png".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S"), self.secondCount)
                cv2.imwrite(self.fileName, self.frame)

                self.uploadFrame()

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

        vs.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stream = GCStream()
    stream.readFrame()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, I finally managed to achieve what I want. The essence is to use Threads in my program so that it will not block the rest of the code from processing.

My program now has separate threads to grab, process and upload frames individually. Hence, one thread is able to collect all images while the other threads will be able to process and upload images at the same time.

```
QUEUE_SIZE = 120

grabbedFrames = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
processFrames = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)


class FrameGraber(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.vs = VideoStream(src=REMOTE_STREAM_MJPEG).start()

    def run(self):
        global grabbedFrames

        while True:
            frame = self.vs.read()
            if frame is not None:
                grabbedFrames.put(frame)
                time.sleep(0.05)


class GCSUploader(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = storage.Client()
        self.bucket = self.client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    def run(self):
        global processFrames

        while True:
            if (not processFrames.empty()):
                fileName = processFrames.get()
                try:
                    blob = self.bucket.blob("{}/{}/{}".format(RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY, fileName))
                    blob.upload_from_filename(os.path.abspath(fileName))
                    print("{} uploaded to {}/{}".format(fileName, RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY))
                    os.remove(fileName)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)


class FrameProcessor(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.secondCount = 0
        self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second

    def run(self):
        global grabbedFrames, processFrames
        while True:

            if datetime.datetime.now().second != self.startSecond:
                self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second
                self.secondCount = 0

            if (not grabbedFrames.empty()):
                frame = grabbedFrames.get()
                self.secondCount = self.secondCount + 1
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, 800)
                fileName = "{}-{}.png".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S"), self.secondCount)
                processFrames.put(fileName)
                cv2.imwrite(fileName, frame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uploader = GCSUploader()
    frameGrabber = FrameGraber()
    frameProcessor = FrameProcessor()

    uploader.start()
    frameGrabber.start()
    frameProcessor.start()

    frameProcessor.join()
    frameGrabber.join()
    uploader.join()
```